# Knowing which <li> item is selected using PHP and mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 questions. One is if there is any error in this code.

The 2nd question I want to ask is how do you know which `<li>` item is selected. Right now, the code performs a search in mySQL for all rows that matches city, language and level and returns the results in a list item.

I want it so that when the user clicks on anyone of the list items, it will goes into another page displaying a more detail description by querying the selected list item.

I have a guess, which is for step 2, I also grab the ID (primary key) for each row and somehow keep that stored within the list but not echo.. Would I need to wrap `<a>` in `<form action="XX.php" method="get">`?

```
<?php
        //1. Define variables
        $find_language = $_GET['find_language'];
        $find_level = $_GET['find_level'];
        $find_city = $_GET['find_city'];

        //2. Perform database query
        $results = mysql_query("
            SELECT name, city, language, level, language_learn, learn_level FROM user 
            WHERE city='{$find_city}' && language='{$find_language}' && level='{$find_level}'", $connection) 
            or die("Database query failed: ". mysql_error());

        //3. Use returned data
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
            echo "<li>";
            echo "<a href=\"#result_detail\" data-transition=\"flow\">";
            echo "<h3>".$row["name"]."</h3>";
            echo "<p>Lives in ".$row["city"]."</p>";
            echo "<p>Knows ".$row["level"]." ".$row["language"]."</p>";
            echo "<p>Wants to learn ".$row["learn_level"]." ".$row["language_learn"]."</p>";
            echo "</a>";
            echo "</li>";}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your code looks alright from what I can see. Does it not work?
2. One way would be to get the ID through your SQL-query as well and then add the id to the `href` in your link. Then you can fetch it through the querystring on the other page, to display the proper post depending on which `li`-element the user clicked on:

   ```
   echo "<a href=\"details.php?id=". $row["id"] ."\" data-transition=\"flow\">";
   ```

Not sure how you mean "somehow keep that stored within the list but not echo" - it wouldn't be possible to store anything in the list, if it is not echoed, as it then wouldn't be sent to the client. You can of course store the id in a data-attribute on the li-element, which won't be displayed to the user. It will however be visible through the source code! Don't know why that should be a problem though?